# AttributeError: Response content isn't text. What is the problem?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using python3.8.5, scrapy2.4.0 I am also using scrapy-proxy-pool and scrapy-user-agents I am getting "AttributeError: Response content isn't text". I am running this code on python3-venv. Would you like to help me explaining and solving the problem ?

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy
import json


class BasisMembersSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'basis'
    allowed_domains = ['www.basis.org.bd']

    def start_requests(self):
        start_url = 'https://basis.org.bd/get-member-list?page=1&team='
        yield scrapy.Request(url=start_url, callback=self.get_membership_no)

    def get_membership_no(self, response):

        data_array = json.loads(response.body)['data']
        next_page = json.loads(response.body)['links']['next']
        
        for data in data_array:
            next_url = 'https://basis.org.bd/get-company-profile/{0}'.format(data['membership_no'])
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_url, callback=self.parse)
            
        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page, callback=self.get_membership_no)

    def parse(self, response):
        print("Printing informations....................................................")
```

Here is my settings.py file:

```
BOT_NAME = 'web_scraping'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['web_scraping.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'web_scraping.spiders'

AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True

# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
#USER_AGENT = 'web_scraping (+http://www.yourdomain.com)'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
PROXY_POOL_ENABLED = True
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    'scrapy_user_agents.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 800,
    'scrapy_proxy_pool.middlewares.ProxyPoolMiddleware': 610,
    'scrapy_proxy_pool.middlewares.BanDetectionMiddleware': 620,
}
```

And are error messages from console output:
[image]
[image]
Thank you...

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557